# nodejs + express file upload tmp name unique

Tags: node.js, express

if I use post to upload a file to my nodejs server I get a temp that looks something like this:

```
/tmp/22608-16eior5.jpg
```

by using this:

```
var tmp_path = req.files.postImage.path;
```

My question is, would the name "22608-16eior5.jpg" be unique enough to be used as a unique filename for one folder full of thousands of others generated the same way?

Or is it recommended that I generate something myself?

Comment: I think for 10000 that's good enough. You have to look at it's generation algorithm/specification. If it's time dependent, you shouldn't worry at all.

Comment: Also delete the files when you are done with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May very well depend on just how many you'll be generating.  If you're unsure, you might wanna take a look at the [node-uuid package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-uuid).

From the docs:

```
// Generate a v4 (random) id
uuid.v4(); // -> '110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1'
```